# Django regroup tag get fields values

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, templatetags

I have a web page where I have two models for Products and Categories. I have this *navbar* where you can filter the `Productos` by categories, so in order to make it dynamic I passed the categories to the *navbar* and then applied a regroup since I'm getting the categories from the model `Products` since is the one the page is using to show the products.

When I try to filter catching the value from the regroup and pass it to my view:

```py
class Categoria_Filter(ListView):
    model = Productos
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = 'mail/category-filter.html'
    

    def get_queryset(self):
        categoria = self.kwargs['slug']
        print(categoria)
        if categoria == 'Todos':
            return Productos.objects.all()
        else:   
            return Productos.objects.filter(categoria = categoria)
```

I get the following result when printing:

```
GroupedResult(grouper=<Categorias: Guantes de Box>, list=[<Productos: Guantes Básico ADX>])
```

which according to the docs is a `namedtuple()`

I have tried the following:

```py
print(getattr(categoria, 'GroupedResult'))
print(getattr(categoria, 'grouper'))
print(getattr(categoria, 'Categorias'))
```

They all give me:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'whatever field I have tried'
```

Also, I print by index and for example:

```py
print(categoria[1])
```

gives me

```
r
```

I know is the `r` from `GroupedResult` and what I want to get from the *namedtuple* is `Guantes de Box` not:

```
GroupedResult(grouper=<Categorias: Guantes de Box>, list=[<Productos: Guantes Básico ADX>])
```

This is the regroup in template:

```
{% regroup object_list by categoria as categoria_list %}
{% for item in categoria_list%}
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-white" href="{% url 'categoria-filter' item %}">{{ item.grouper }}</a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the below line which you have in your `get_queryset()` of your class-based view:

> ```py
> categoria = self.kwargs['slug']
> ```

`categoria` is the value of `'slug'` key in the request and of course it is an instance of `str` data type in python programming language.

But based on what I can find out from your question you need to `Guantes de Box` and with the below code and in `{{ x.grouper }}`, you can see the phrase `Guantes de Box`.

```
{% regroup object by object.property as newname %}

{% for x in newname %}
  {{ x.grouper }} --> this expression gives you the grouper names
  {% for y in x.list %}
    <p>{{ y.blobfield }}: {{ y.blobblobfield }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: let me edit my question, adding the template code

Comment: you know what, you saved me, I change the href like this: href="{% url 'categoria-filter' item.grouper %}" and it worked!

Comment: It's good for me, be successful and go on :)